# Could not find handler chain file handler-chain.xml for class

Tags: java, batch-file, soap, cxf, ws-security

I am able to invoke client application using run.bat file.
Please find below is **run.bat** file content.

lcp.bat file content

```
 SET LCP=%LCP%;%*
```

run.bat file content

```
   @ECHO OFF
    SET LCP=.
    FOR /R lib %%i IN ("*.jar") DO CALL lcp.bat %%i
    echo "target/classes;%LCP%"
        echo
        echo "test validation..."
        java -cp "target\\classes;%LCP%" com.tfp.ipr.soap.Client  "https://webservice.ibancomplete.com/ibanws/services/IBANService?wsdl" validate "ME25525440003582070092" 
        pause
```

Invoking client application using bat file is working as expected. This bat file i am invoking from the windows command prompt. 
**Additional information** This client application uses below jars.

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cxf-2.7.3.jar
httpasyncclient-4.0-beta3.jar
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.2.jar
httpcore-nio-4.2.2.jar
neethi-3.0.2.jar
openws-1.4.2-1.jar
spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
169,749 spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.6.9.jar
xmlschema-core-2.0.2.jar
xmlsec-1.5.2.jar
```

**Problem**: what i did is , i bundled all contents of classes folder as single jar (IbanWs-Client.jar).  i have executed using below command. Please refer below screenshot and advise solution.[image]

Answer (score -1):

First solution : Move all the jars in jre lib directory and so that these jars will be loaded at the time jvm initialization. You can able to run the program.